# tkinder.TclError bad event type or keysym "key"

Tags: python, tkinter

****im running this on raspberry pi 3 b+***
im doing a school project and  was following along with a tutorial on Tkinter and i tried to run my program but it gives me an error

im kind of a noob to pyhton so not very sure

```
   import RPi.GPIO as gpio
   import time
   import sys
    import Tkinter as tk

    def init():
            gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
            gpio.setup(16, gpio.OUT)
            gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)
            gpio.setup(13, gpio.OUT)
            gpio.setup(15, gpio.OUT)

    def forward(tf):
        gpio.output(16, True)
        time.sleep(tf)
        gpio.cleanup()

    def reverse(tf):
        gpio.output(16, False)
      gpio.cleanup()

    def pr(tf):
           gpio.output(16, False)

        time.sleep(tf)
       gpio.cleanup()

    def pl(tf):
        gpio.output(16, True)

    gpio.cleanup()

def tl(tf):
    gpio.output(16, True)

    gpio.cleanup()

def tr(tf):
    gpio.output(16, False)

    gpio.cleanup()


def key_input(event):
    init()
    print "key :", event.char
    key_press = event.char
    st = 0.030

    if key_press.lower() == 'w':
        forward(st)
    elif key_press.lower() == 's':
        reverse(st)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'a':
        pl(st)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'd':
        pr(st)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'q':
        tl(st)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'e':
        tr(st)


command = tk.Tk()
```

> here it shows an error it says command.bind('', key_input)
>   file "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinder.py", line 1106 in bind return self._bind(('bind', self._W ), sequence, func, add)
>   file "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinder.py", line 1061 in bind return self.tk.call (what + (sequence,cmd)
>   _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "key"

```
command.bind('<key>', key_input)
command.pack()
command.mainloop()
```

it should open up a window where i could just press any key and it takes it as an input

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There's no need to have dozens of calls to gpio functions for the purpose of this question.

Comment: is this okay? can u help me please? what is wrong in this program

Comment: it has to be `<Key>` with upper `K`

Comment: For this particular problem you can remove almost all of the functions (`pr`, `pl`, `reverse`, etc. Keep removing code until the problem goes away, and that will be a clue as to where the problem lies.

Comment: @BryanOakley i have tried the code firstly without tk just running those simple function and calling them they were fine it was only after tk this error started to occur

Comment: @furas ooooommmmmgggggg thank u so much i cannot believe it I missed to capitalize it thank u so much

Comment: @sarfarazsaleem: yes, that's my point. This is a problem with your tk code, so we don't need the other code to reproduce this problem.